# Android Kotlin - How to use flow.CollectLatest{ } in a loop

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I need to use flow.collectLatest {} in my fragment in OnViewCreated, and then in a loop under some condition multiple times (I made a filter, so each time different data should be retrieved).
This is my code for calling collectLatest:

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
     myViewModel.myFlow.collectLatest { pagingData ->
           myAdapter.submitData(pagingData)
           myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
     }
}
```

I use this block of code in both onViewCreated and in the loop.
However, it gets called only once, in OnViewCreated.
In the loop, sometimes it gets called, and then it needs 2-3min to retrieve data, but most of the time nothing changes.
I guess it could be an issue related to needing much more time to retrieve data, or it just shouldn't be used this way.
Some of the possible solutions I tried, but didn't work:

1. using delay
2. adding flowOn(Despatchers.IO) in the end of the flow
3. switching flow call to a different thread

Comment: Your `myViewModel.myFlow` should be a StateFlow and you should only collect it in onviewcreated and it will collect the newest data whenever it's emitted. What would collecting it again in loop to update same adapter supposed to accomplish?

Comment: I have a recycler view that, when it is scrolled, data needs to be changed

Comment: Correct design to change data would be to query your viewmodel to update `myFlow` which would trigger collection you established in onviewcreated, I don't see where loop comes in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop for this, should only collect it on onViewCreated() once time. You should have two flows(one for your filter and another for your data) and to use switcMap(), and your adapter/view should call viewModel to notify any change that to be done.

Here an example:

```
//you can use any object type for your filter, in this example i used a sealed class
private val _transactionFilter = MutableLiveData<TransactionFilter>(
        TransactionFilter.TransactionsByDate(Date())
    )

val transactions: LiveData<Data> = _transactionFilter.switchMap { filter ->
        //code to return data
    }
```

Kotlin Flow's have a switchMap() too, i used liveData because flow.switchMap was experimental yet.

Another thing: you don't need call `notifiyDataSetChanged()` when using ListAdapter